# Calculating limits of function

Tags: calculus, limits

On practical classes at university we calculated some limits of functions of the following type: 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)^{k(x)}$$
The key idea was that we know that $\exists \lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = p \in \mathbb{R}$ (usually $p = e$). So we put this result in our initial expression:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)^{k(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0}p^{k(x)}$$
How can this step be proved formally? Probably, to prove this should be used variable substitution, but in such case I have ho ideas how to deal with $k(x)$.

upd: Ok, this cannot be proved in general, but what if $f(x) =(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be proven formally, because it isn't true in general. Take $f(x) = 1 - x$, and $k(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Then $p = 1$, and so $\lim_{x\to 0}p^{k(x)} = 1$, but $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)^{k(x)} = \frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: thanks. Can you find counterexample for $f(x) = (1 + x)^\frac{1}{x}$ ?